# Loading image from a resource Can't read input file

Tags: java, image

I am trying to load a resource image, but I am getting an error that says:
`javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!`

```
if(full.equals("")){
    try{
        full = HomePage.class.getResource("/images/default.jpg").getPath();
        System.out.println(full);
        File imgPath = new File(full);
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(imgPath);
        WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
        DataBufferByte data = (DataBufferByte)raster.getDataBuffer();
        full = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(data.getData());
    }catch(IOException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(HomePage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

When I print out the variable `full`, I get the following location:
`file:/C:/Users/rnaddy/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Phantom%20Browser/dist/run1534966744/Phantom_Browser.jar!/images/default.jpg`

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe you have an invalid image..

Comment: I created the image with photoshop, so it shouldn't be invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageIO knows how to read from jar files, so you can just say

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(HomePage.class.getResource("/images/default.jpg"));
```

As for why your solution doesn't work, `getResource` returns a URL. If you print it out when you run your application through the jar, you'll see that it returns `jar:file:/path/to/file` for the resource, whereas if you ran `getPath` and printed that out, you'll see `file:/path/to/file`.

Presumably, `ImageIO` will handle the input differently depending on what kind of URL you pass in.